# Windows 7 file order dysfunction

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In Windows 7, my files always went into alphabetical order when I viewed them in a folder.

One day last year I found the most recently created were listing at the top in the folder from the Windows Explorer view and not in alphabetical order, but only in chronological order.

How can I get the files to list in alphabetical order again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click in the folder then select "Sort by" -> "Name" and "Ascending".  When it is sorting files/shortcuts are sorted alphabetically separate from folders.